# Override Equals in partial class

Tags: .net, entity-framework, partial-classes

I'm using EF 4.3. In order to extend the functionity of entity classes I create partial classes. This works fine in the main.

The framework creates 1 to many navigation properties as hashsets and I have a need to change a number of these, as they contain item lists that are manipulated by the user during a site visit.

Ideally what I would like to do is provide overrides to Equals and HashCode, however the code doesn't compile, instead giving the message "no suitable method found to override".

Are there any work-arounds for this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not much code in your question to start from :), but generally to add custom equlity members you would create a second part of the partial class and let it implement  the [`IEquatable<T>` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187.aspx).

If you do that it is also advisable to override the non generic equality members `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()` of `Object`, which you should always be able to override. Maybe the exception is caused by you using "HashCode" in stead of "GetHashCode".

A simple example:

```
public partial class EntityClass : IEquatable<EntityClass>
{
    public bool Equals(EntityClass other)
    {
        return this.Id == other.Id;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object other)
    {
        return (other is EntityClass)
            && this.Id == ((EntityClass)other).Id;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return this.Id.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked the issue out. Due to missing the Equals(object other) part of code, but error message was slightly misleading.